# Is it possible to create content selectors for helm hosted repo in NXRM

Tags: repository, nexus, kubernetes-helm

I want to create a subpath for each team in helm hosted repository, and apply some content selectors to restrict access (each team will have only access to a subset of helm charts, or can upload to a specific subpath) as we can do with docker or raw repos.

Is there a way to do that or content selectors not supported for helm hosted repo in NXRM3 OSS.
Thanks in advance for any idea or any advice to achieve that.

If you have other ideas how to secure access or upload to helm hosted repo that will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

Helm was added to the application not via plugin in 3.21 for OSS (and Pro licensed).
Content selectors should work for Helm the same as any format.  They are path based primarily at this time, so it's up to you to figure out what path works for your teams.  If they were to put teamAlpha in the path, then it'd be easy, for example.

See more general details here: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Content+Selectors

If you only have 2 teams, you could also do security based permissions, however, this doesn't scale well, so generally is not recommended.

Comment: the problem here is that i cannot create paths inside helm repo

Comment: @Adamsin You mean for your Helm components you can't give them a specific path?

Comment: @Adamsin Fair enough, I don't think there's a workaround there.  Either you would need the portions your company can control to be selectable or path won't work for you.  But all that is implemented (any format) is path.  Another option would be repository per team, but that may or may not scale.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the developers to include a prefix in the chart name. If the name in chart.yaml is `name: teamA-app` then you can create a content selector like `format == "helm" and path =^ "teamA-"`.
If you want the helm CLI tool to work, you also need to add permission to index.yaml. So the content selector would be `format == "helm" and (path =^ "teamA-" or path == "index.yaml")`